# sorting String DateAndTime value in a list of class

Tags: c#

I am using a class that has an attribute DateAndTime of type string. I have create a list of this class and try to sort that list according to dates in descending order. but my problem is that how can i sort DateAndTime because it is in string format.

```
var DateTimeSortedRecords = ProductList(d => new
        {
            d.dt.Date,
            d.CreatedDate.Month,
            d.CreatedDate.year,
        })
            .OrderByDescending(d => d.Year)
            .ThenByDescending(d => d.Month)
            .ThenByDescending(d => d.Date).ToList();
```

------------DATA------------------

Monday, 01 October 2015 05:50:06

Friday, 29 December 2018 05:50:06

Monday, 09 October 2015 05:50:06

Friday, 29 December 2011 05:50:06

Friday, 29 May 2015 05:50:06

------------OUTPUT I WANT---------------

Friday, 29 December 2018 05:50:06

Monday, 09 October 2015 05:50:06

Monday, 01 October 2015 05:50:06

Friday, 29 May 2015 05:50:06

Friday, 29 December 2011 05:50:06

Comment: Better you convert the string to DateTime and then perform sort operation

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with something like the following:

```cs
var dates = new List<DateTime>
{
    new DateTime(2000, 10, 10),
    new DateTime(2010, 10, 10)
};

var sortedDates = dates.OrderByDescending(x => x).Select(x => x.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss"));

foreach (var item in sortedDates)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

This should be all you need, if you just want the output and do not care about the sorted `DateTime` objects themselfs.

Comment: Hi, your answer is useful for me thank u so much.. my am not expert in linq query.. can you please see my below code. i have achieved my desire output but i think my logic is not optimize.. 
i have post an answer will you please check this?

Answer (score -1):

i have achieved my desire output but i think my logic is not optimize..

```
    //get all string dates from product list
    var GetDates = ProductList.Select(m => m.CreatedDate).ToList();

    //create DateTime list to convert the string dates to DateTime Formate
    List<DateTime> dt = new List<DateTime>();
    foreach (var item in GetDates)
    {
        dt.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(item));
    }

    //sort the DateTime "dt" list
    var SortedDatesList = dt.OrderByDescending(x => x)
        .Select(x => x.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"));

    //Create a list of Class Product , and add products according to sorted dates
    List<Product> _NewProducts = new List<Product>();
    foreach (var item in SortedDatesList)
    {
        _NewProducts.Add(ProductList.Where(m=>m.CreatedDate == item).FirstOrDefault());
    }
```